# What is France's traditional costume?

Tags: france, local-customs, culture, clothing, local-knowledge

I like to see, and sometimes buy, traditional clothes when traveling in a new country.

Though you seldom see people in poncho and sombrero in Mexico (at least in the Federal District), you can see many people in kimono in Japan, and some people in hanbok in Korea.

**What about France** ? What is the traditional French costume? Are there places (religious buildings, ceremonies, festivals,...) where I have a reasonable chance to see them?

In all my time in France, I could only see the typical Western modern combination of jean/pants+t-shirt/shirt/polo.

Comment: Labeling people as Muslim or Roman Catholic is quite inappropriate when speaking about contemporary secular France. Although the population coming from Maghreb or Western Africa, or their descendants, is an integral part of French modern culture, I don't think anyone would consider boubou or djellaba as a French traditional costume.  France had been historically mainly Roman Catholic, but I am not sure how this factors in how French people traditionally dressed... and, except if Lithuanian has another meaning I am not aware, I don't think it is "easy" to see Lithuanian in France.

Comment: I would be very happy to hear why VTClosers consider this question too broad. Would "Where can I see people wearing kimonos in Japan" be too broad?

Comment: @Taladris it's a widespread attitude I've seen on most of the SE network. When people (especially rep hunters) do not know how the reply to a question because they don't can't find a proper way to do it, they flag the question instead of their ignorance. This question is pretty simple and straightforward; and I voted to keep it open (although I'm not aware of a national costume in France, and I seriously doubt there is one)

Comment: I don't think there's a national traditional costume, though there are quite a few regional ones. Note however that I doubt you will see anyone wear one for anything else that a festival of some kind, you'll hardly see people wearing one like you could see Japanese wearing kimonos.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about travel.

Comment: No need to closevote, OP mentions that they want to buy a souvenir while in France and are therefor looking for the 'national costume'.

Comment: @fkraiem: is finding how to experience the local culture off-topic?

Comment: I'm french, and as @Willeke said, we don't realy have a traditional costume. But the image of us is a bald man wearing a beret cycling whith a french baguette in the hand :) hope i've help you.

Comment: I did ask a (frighteningly smart) colleague about the [beret, scarf and striped shirt](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/84/b7/04/84b7048a45671a433152179ef7971c27.jpg) and he claimed never in his life to have seen anyone dressed as such.

Comment: @verbalki - Speaking as a Brit, I think I should let you know that you're also supposed to have a string of onions around your neck.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany It'd be interesting to learn why that became such a universally recognized symbol of Frenchness, to be honest.

Comment: Perhaps an important note that applies to Europe: the modern European countries do *not* match on *old* cultures. For example Germany, Italy and Spain are good examples of countries that group cultures together: Germany consists out of a large number of 16 states that all have their own history, culture,... Because of the European history and wars, different regions, can have a different culture and it is usually because of conquests and wars that they ended up being part of this or that country.

Comment: @Casey A quite reasonable-sounding web reference links the beret to late 19th- early 20th century French onion salesmen ["onion johnnies"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onion_Johnny)  from Brittany. Since that was often the only contact English folks had with the French, [the reference](https://curiousrambler.com/2015/10/02/berets-onions-and-stereotypes/) claims that they assumed all French wore berets. The French sailor shirt is reasonably well known and sometimes seen.

Comment: It is surprisingly rare to see someone wearing a kilt in modern-day Scotland, but that doesn't mean that it is no longer a national costume.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

France has been unified as a country for longer than many European ones, and the 19th century didn't see the development of a specific French national costume (unless you see the international influence of French fashion as a costume issue).

Even though there are some surviving bits of regional costume, there is no one French national costume.  These regional costumes were largely codified in the 19th century, pretty much as they were disappearing from general use.  Some regions have held on longer, for instance it's less unusual to see older Breton women in lace caps on holidays than to see Alsacian women in their corresponding butterfly hats.

The things that American think of as 'national' were just fashion fads (often based in former regional costumes) at times when Americans were around France a lot.  So the post-WWI fad of Basque berets is perceived as specifically French, even though it's equally Spanish, and nobody bats an eye at pairing it with the Picasso-led fad for Breton striped fishing shirts (or the overlapping 50s bikinis).  To this day the French are much more fashion-oriented and conformist in clothing than Americans, which can lead to endless books about how little black dresses or tan raincoats are national costumes.  The authors of these books usually go home and ignore the fact that the following year the same people will all be wearing red dresses and black quilted coats, or whatever.

Answer (score 46):

France does not really have one national costume.

There are many regional costumes, although not many or even non is/are still used as daily dress.

In the last half of the 20th century, the 'typical' French male item was a [beret.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beret)
And it is still used as a cartoon image for the French.

If you are on the French coast you will likely also see a lot of [striped shirts.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marini%C3%A8re) I have never seen them inland and I have seen them on the coast of other European countries, but they do fit with the English ['French guy'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onion_Johnny) image. ([Results of image search here.](https://www.google.nl/search?biw=1299&bih=702&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=1GUZWrjOD8y1sAfg-rp4&q=onion%20johnny%20picture&oq=onion%20johnny%20picture&gs_l=psy-ab.3...3565.3565.0.4080.1.1.0.0.0.0.94.94.1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.BiizoxLLels))

It is likely as 'traditional' and 'national' as the poncho for Mexico.

Comment: I would second the Beret. About as stereo-typically French as you can get without putting garlic around your neck and holding a baguette.

Comment: @SGR the garlic stereotype is only present in UK tho...

Comment: @Antzi I'd say the garlic/baguett stereotype is quite populra in both Sweden and Germany as well.

Comment: @Antzi I thought it was more a general Western/Central European stereotype of the French

Comment: +1 for the first sentence alone.  [Brittany in particular](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=breton+national+dress&num=50&tbm=isch) has a very distinctive national dress (which is only ever seen on special/traditional occasions)

Comment: Not just Brittany, but Alsace, Basque country, Normandy, Burgundy ... Like many large countries, France is a patchwork of areas with different cultures coming from different places, most of them having their own traditional costume, local gastronomy, and some of them even retaining their local dialect to this day.

Comment: @SGR Now you have me looking for *'Allo 'allo* videos ...

Comment: have a look at this: http://www.topito.com/top-costumes-traditionnels-ridicules

Comment: Actually the marinière (the striped shirt you describe) was advertised a couple years ago when a Minister wanted to promote "Made in France" products. He famously posed with one. http://www.huffingtonpost.fr/2012/10/18/arnaud-montebourg-defend-son-style-mariniere-defenseur-industrie-francaise_n_1977641.html

Comment: In addition to the mariniere and beret, you will need garlic, a wheel of cheese, a bottle of wine, a twirled moustache and an accordion.

Comment: For the beret I would not say last half of the 20th century, but during 30's, 40's and 50's, maybe up to 60's. In 1990's that was not the case !

Comment: I am a member of a group that has about 30 French people meeting once a year. Out of them 3 or 4 will wear a beret. So while not massive, still very much alive.

Comment: @PeterWone: you did not list probably the most important item: a baguette. Otherwise this is an accurate picture of the everyday's passer-by in France.

Comment: @WoJ I gave him a baguette but he ate it while I was setting up the camera.

Answer (score 6):

As your question doesn't specify it has to be in France, you may want to try [Little World Museum of Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_World_Museum_of_Man), which is in near Nagoya, Japan. You can't purchase clothing, but you can wear clothing for a small fee. Look for "Alsace village" within the park. The women's dresses there are very similar to those for Alsace in Nic's answer. Even though the place may sound like a theme park, I was pleasantly surprised at how informative it was.

I don't have a clue as to whether France has national dresses, or mainly has regional dresses. I assume regional dresses are just as good as national dresses for your purposes.

As rather generic advice, rural areas or small towns and former colonies often keep more of a region or country's (or coloniser's) cultural heritage than the big cities. I suspect that the colonies in the Pacific are more likely to keep France's heritage than those in Africa, because the former may have less enmity towards France than the latter.

Comment: There is neither French nor German dress.  And Alsace is a fairly independent region, after being yanked back and forth against their will so many times.  As to colonies, obviously the further ones would be less influenced, seeing how air travel didn't get really widespread before they got their independence.

Comment: @GeorgeM The comment about Alsace was intended as a joke (I learnt about it while studying the treaty of Versailles), but I've removed it.

Answer (score 3):

Some styles can be recognized as French, meaning that you can realistically expect some French people to sometimes wear it, and if anywhere in the world you meet someone wearing that then there is a slightly higher probability that they are French:

[image]

But such styles are not typically described as "traditional".

"Traditional" costumes exist, but they differ widely from a region to another, here are a few examples from various regions:

[image] (Bretagne)
[image] (New Caledonia)
[image] (Basque)
[image] (Alsace)
(etc)

As you can see, they have very little in common.

Comment: Thanks for the Alsace images. Very similar to the ones in Little World, but I didn't want to upload them because they're of strangers.